# ¿Consultar en mongoDB una subcolección?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

Me enfrento a un  gran problema dado que quiero verificar que un registro no existe en mi base de datos antes de insertarlo.

La cuestión es que estoy utilizando laravel con la librería jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. Y necesito que el campo que quiero que sea único se verifique en una sola consulta a pesar de que sea una subcolección.

```
Modelo::where('padre->hijo', '=', $data)->count();
```

La colección tiene esta forma:

```
{
    _id: "id_sql",
    general_data: {
       campo_1: "", // campo que quiero verificar que sea único
       Campo_2: ""
    }
}
```

Si alguien se le ocurre como podría ser la consulta con eloquent o directamente con el método:

```
DB::query('');
```

Se lo agradeceré que ponga un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta más simple utilizando eloquent es tener la siguiente sintaxis para consultar subcolecciones:

```
Modelo::where('llave.subllave', '=', $data)->get();
```